# How to get this javascript redirect to work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have got help here to put together this code. And it works perfect in Chrome, Safari and in Internet Explorer. But in Firefox it redirects to a sub-url (probably not right word for it...)

I have the script on a page:

http://example.com/test

[image]

And I want to redirect to a new page based on the value the user chooses (and then click the button): So if I choose option #2 I want to get to here: http://example.com/my-test-2

It works in the other browsers, **but not in Firefox**. In Firefox it in stead redirects to:
http://example.com/test?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy-test-2
which of course doesn't lead anywhere.

The HTML is loaded in a jquery and Bootstrap environment, and I do use modals on that page. I just mention this in case there is a know error for Firefox using those framworks.

Here is the HTML:

```html
I want to choose:
<form  id="mychoice">
    <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/my-test-1"><span>1</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/my-test-2"><span>2</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/my-test-3"><span>3</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/my-test-4"><span>4</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/my-test-5"><span>5</span><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="See result">
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#mychoice").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var loc = $('input[name="redirect"]:checked').val();
        window.location = loc;
        return false;    
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Preben/s3pv5t3g/)

**Do you see the reason why Firefox behaves like this?**

If of interest: I work on a Mac OSX 10.10.2 with Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit), Firefox 37.0.2 and Windows 8.1 IE 11.09600.17728

Comment: `Do you see the reason why Firefox behaves like this?` You should really debug your code using browser console, this would be fixed really really quickly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've used `preventDefault()`, but haven't actually passed the `event` in to the handler. Also note that using `window.location.assign()` is better practice. Try this:

```
$("#mychoice").submit(function(event) { // < 'event' is the parameter passed to the func
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign($('input[name="redirect"]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tested in the fiddle, and it worked there. Going to test on my site. Thank you Rory. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Preben/s3pv5t3g/3/

Comment: I will just confirm that this worked in my site too. I will chosse this as my answer, but it's too early now. (Am not allowed yet.)

Answer (score 0):

you have an error un your JS. The variable event is not defined.
Try it like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mychoice").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var loc = $('input[name="redirect"]:checked').val();
        window.location.href = loc;
        return false;    
    });
});
```